# Trouble Dockerizing Django Application

Tags: python, django, docker, anaconda

I'm working on Dockerizing a Django application with a Conda environment, but I'm encountering issues.

The issue is that when I run docker compose up my Django application does not start properly and hangs on system check.

This is my DockerFile setup:

```
    # Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
    FROM continuumio/miniconda3
    
    # Set the working directory to /webapp
    WORKDIR /webapp
    
    # Copy the conda environment file to the container
    COPY webapp/my_env.yml .
    
    # Create the conda environment
    RUN conda env create -f my_env.yml
    
    # Create the conda environment
    SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "my_env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
    
    # Copy the current directory contents into the container at webapp
    COPY webapp .
    
    # List the contents of the directory
    RUN conda run -n my_env ls
    
    # Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
    EXPOSE 8000
    
    # Run the Django development server
    ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "my_env", "python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: webapp_connect
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Replace with the actual path to your Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
   
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

And this is a snippet from my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "webapp_connect",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "tcatca124",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

This is the output I get when running "docker compose up":

```
dockercompose
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ db Pulled                                                                                                                                           1.7s
[+] Building 5.3s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                           docker:default
 => [webapp internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 874B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                    0.6s
 => [webapp 1/6] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3@sha256:5ee0ed861bce8f67acb0a3e8a416891781db54302d93bf20a3c6301d7683d7b9                     0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load build context                                                                                                           4.7s
 => => transferring context: 54.54kB                                                                                                                   4.7s
 => CACHED [webapp 2/6] WORKDIR /webapp                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 3/6] COPY webapp/myenv.yml .                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 4/6] RUN conda env create -f myenv.yml                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 5/6] COPY webapp .                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 6/6] RUN conda run -n myenv_clean ls                                                                                   0.0s
 => [webapp] exporting to image                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:80f8dcf1213b1d1be5eefae1dabb9e344738f94646ef6dd855fa0a932af3c575                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/root-webapp                                                                                              0.0s
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container root-db-1          Created                                                                                                         0.0s
 ✔ Container root-webapp-1  Created                                                                                                         0.0s
Attaching to root-db-1, root-webapp-1
root-db-1          |
root-db-1          | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
root-db-1          |
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.191 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.192 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.192 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.195 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.201 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-11-27 16:12:13 UTC
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.416 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.419 UTC [29] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1954A38
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.419 UTC [29] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1954A70: expected at least 24, got 0
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.419 UTC [29] LOG:  redo done at 0/1954A38 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.423 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.432 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.010 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/1954A70, redo lsn=0/1954A70
root-db-1          | 2023-11-27 16:18:29.435 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
root-webapp-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
root-webapp-1  | System check identified some issues:
root-webapp-1  |
root-webapp-1  | WARNINGS:
root-webapp-1  | ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/webapp/barplots/static/piecharts/scatter' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
root-webapp-1  |
root-webapp-1  | System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!